# Writing XML from parsed data

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have written a piece of code that parses links from the top navigation from a website.

```
private string url = "http://www.blah.com/";
    private HtmlWeb web;
    private HtmlDocument doc;

    private string topNavName = "";
    private string topNavUrl = "";

    public void Setup()
    {
        try
        {
            web = new HtmlWeb();
            doc = web.Load(url);
            web.AutoDetectEncoding = true;
            TopCats();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There has been an issue loading url {0}", e);
        }
    }

    private List<Catalogue> TopCats()
    {
      List<Catalogue> GetTop = new List<Catalogue>();
        try
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection TopNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='TopTabs1_tabs']/li/span/a");
            if (TopNode != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode Topitem in TopNode)
                {
                    topNavName = Topitem.InnerText;
                    topNavUrl = url + Topitem.Attributes["href"].Value;

                    Catalogue xmltopcat = new Catalogue();
                    xmltopcat.indentifier = "here";
                    xmltopcat.name = topNavName;
                    xmltopcat.url = topNavUrl;
                    xmltopcat.description = "";

                    Console.WriteLine("Category >> {0}",topNavName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There has been an issue Top Nav {0}", e);
        }
        return GetTop;
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that I am not sure how to make each parsed data in the `for each` loop fill the XML elements. For the mapping on the XML I have created a new class:

```
class Catalogue
{
    [XmlElement("Category identifier")]
    public string indentifier
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string url
    { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description
    { get; set; }
}
```

I am really not sure to create a XML document- I have tried a few things, and I am really am not sure what I am doing. I am still learning C# and this is my first time working with XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting parsed html to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713375/converting-parsed-html-to-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).First store your all `Catalogues` into a `List`.

```
Catalogue xmltopcat = new Catalogue();
xmltopcat.indentifier = "here";
xmltopcat.name = topNavName;
xmltopcat.url = topNavUrl;
xmltopcat.description = "";
GetTop.Add(xmltopcat); // <-- add current catalogue to the list
```

Then call `TopCats` method and get your list and create XML file:

```
var list = TopCats();

XElement xDoc  = new XElement("Catalogues", 
                              list.Select(c => new XElement("Catalogue",
                              new XElement("indentifier",c.indentifier)
                              new XElement("name",c.name)
                              new XElement("url",c.url)
                              new XElement("description",c.description)));
xDoc.Save("savepath");
```

Or you can use `XmlSerializer`

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("records.xml",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Catalogue>),new XmlRootAttribute("Catalogues"));
serializer.Serialize(fs,list);
```